# Heroku: Command errored out with exit status 128

Tags: python, git, heroku

I am trying to create a Heroku app that imports a private repo. I have everything set up, including:

- Valid BUILDPACK_SSH_KEY
- Buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ssh-key.git
- git+ssh://git@github.com/me/private-repo.git line in requirements (obviously changed to the actual repo path name)
- All other files needed to produce a Heroku app (e.g. app.py, requirements, Procfile, gitignore, Aptfile for opencv, runtime.txt for specific version of Python, and other local .py files for the app).

It was running just fine earlier, and apart from the fact that the app is a few MB over the max slug size (500 MB), it seemed to be importing. Now, I'm getting the following message when trying to deploy, and I can't quite figure out how to connect to the repo.

Note that the app works when I copy needed parts of the private repo into the folder that gets pushed, so it shouldn't be an error with the app itself, just the connection/installation of the private repo.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. heroku-community/apt
       2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ssh-key.git
       3. heroku/python
-----> Apt app detected
-----> Reusing cache
-----> Updating apt caches
       Hit:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
       Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
       Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
       Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
       Fetched 223 kB in 1s (294 kB/s)
       Reading package lists...
-----> Fetching .debs for libsm6
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/16.1 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libxrender1
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/18.7 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libfontconfig1
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/114 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libice6
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/41.0 kB of archives.
       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Fetching .debs for libgl1
       Reading package lists...
       Building dependency tree...
       The following additional packages will be installed:
         libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1
         libdrm2 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0
         libllvm11 libpciaccess0 libsensors-config libsensors5 libvulkan1
         libwayland-client0 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0
         libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxdamage1
         libxfixes3 libxshmfence1 libxxf86vm1 mesa-vulkan-drivers
       Suggested packages:
         pciutils lm-sensors
       The following NEW packages will be installed:
         libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1
         libdrm2 libgl1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0
         libllvm11 libpciaccess0 libsensors-config libsensors5 libvulkan1
         libwayland-client0 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0
         libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxdamage1
         libxfixes3 libxshmfence1 libxxf86vm1 mesa-vulkan-drivers
       0 upgraded, 31 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
       Need to get 0 B/32.2 MB of archives.
       After this operation, 401 MB of additional disk space will be used.
       Download complete and in download only mode
-----> Installing libdrm2_2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libdrm-common_2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1_all.deb
-----> Installing libdrm-intel1_2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libdrm-nouveau2_2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libdrm-radeon1_2.4.102-1ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libfontconfig1_2.13.1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libgl1_1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libgl1-mesa-dri_20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libglapi-mesa_20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libglvnd0_1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libglx0_1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libglx-mesa0_20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libice6_2%3a1.0.10-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libllvm11_1%3a11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libpciaccess0_0.16-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libsensors5_1%3a3.6.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libsensors-config_1%3a3.6.0-2ubuntu1_all.deb
-----> Installing libsm6_2%3a1.2.3-1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libvulkan1_1.2.131.2-1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libwayland-client0_1.18.0-1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libx11-xcb1_2%3a1.6.9-2ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxcb-dri2-0_1.14-2_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxcb-dri3-0_1.14-2_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxcb-glx0_1.14-2_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxcb-present0_1.14-2_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxcb-randr0_1.14-2_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxcb-sync1_1.14-2_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxcb-xfixes0_1.14-2_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxdamage1_1%3a1.1.5-2_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxfixes3_1%3a5.0.3-2_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxrender1_1%3a0.9.10-1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxshmfence1_1.3-1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing libxxf86vm1_1%3a1.1.4-1build1_amd64.deb
-----> Installing mesa-vulkan-drivers_20.2.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
-----> Writing profile script
-----> Rewrite package-config files
-----> heroku-buildpack-ssh-key app detected
-----> Install heroku-buildpack-ssh-key
-----> Installed SSH key from BUILDPACK_SSH_KEY
-----> Python app detected
 !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.10
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
-----> Installing python-3.7.9
-----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting git+ssh://****@github.com/me/private-repo.git (from -r /tmp/build_ede3698e/requirements.txt (line 33))
         Cloning ssh://****@github.com/me/private-repo.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-xrwjgy49
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'ssh://****@github.com/me/private-repo.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-xrwjgy49 Check the logs for full command output.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just mis-typed the name of the repo.